# Count Unique Occurrences in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row called `Name`.

There are about 20k values in it. How would I get a unique count of the values in the row? I want bob to be counted once and not 5 or 6 times. Thank you in advance.

*Name*

> bob324
>    sally34
>    may324

etc (20k values)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the first row in the column has a column header.

On the Data menu, point to Filter, and then click Advanced Filter.

In the Advanced Filter dialog box, click Copy to another location.

If the range that you are counting is not already selected, delete any information in the List range box and then click the column (or select the range) that contains your data.
In the Copy to box, delete any information in the box or click in the box, and then click a blank column where you want to copy the unique values.

Select the Unique records only check box, and click OK.

The unique values from the selected range are copied to the new column.

In the blank cell below the last cell in the range, enter the ROWS function. Use the range of unique values that you just copied as the argument. For example, if the range of unique values is B1:B45, then enter: =ROWS(first,last)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "row" you mean column, apply Remove Duplicates and observe on screen message (then Undo, if desired).

Answer (score 0):

something like this will count the number of unique items in `A1:A20000`

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A20000,A1:A20000))`